# Relative weight within row with max value in python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, lambda

I try to calculate the relative weights of `df1` in each row with a max value of 0.5. So far, I was able to calculate the relative weights in `df2` but without an upper boundary. Here would be a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    'ID1':[0,0,2,1,1], 
    'ID2':[1,3,1,1,2],
    'ID3':[1,0,0,1,0],
    'ID4':[1,1,7,1,0],
    'ID5':[0,6,0,0,1]})

df1:
    Dates       ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5
0   2021-01-01  0   1   1   1   0
1   2021-01-02  0   3   0   1   6
2   2021-01-03  2   1   0   7   0
3   2021-01-04  1   1   1   1   0
4   2021-01-05  1   2   0   0   1
```

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Dates').T
df2 = df1.transform(lambda x: x/sum(x)).T
df2.round(2)

df2:            
Dates       ID1     ID2     ID3     ID4     ID5         
2021-01-01  0.00    0.33    0.33    0.33    0.00
2021-01-02  0.00    0.30    0.00    0.10    0.60
2021-01-03  0.20    0.10    0.00    0.70    0.00
2021-01-04  0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.00
2021-01-05  0.25    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.25
```

I try to get `df3` with a relative weight maximum of 0.5.

```
df3:            
Dates       ID1     ID2     ID3     ID4     ID5         
2021-01-01  0.00    0.33    0.33    0.33    0.00
2021-01-02  0.00    0.30    0.00    0.10    0.50
2021-01-03  0.20    0.10    0.00    0.50    0.00
2021-01-04  0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25    0.00
2021-01-05  0.25    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.25
```

When I use the following adjusted function, I get the error: `Transform function failed`

```
df1.transform(lambda x: x/sum(x) if x/sum(x) < 0.5 else 0.5).T
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of transposing and applying transformations on each element, we can manipulate rows directly.

```
df3 = df1.copy().set_index('Dates')
df3 = df3.div(df3.sum(axis=1), axis=0).clip(upper=0.5).round(2).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        Dates   ID1   ID2   ID3   ID4   ID5
0  2021-01-01  0.00  0.33  0.33  0.33  0.00
1  2021-01-02  0.00  0.30  0.00  0.10  0.50
2  2021-01-03  0.20  0.10  0.00  0.50  0.00
3  2021-01-04  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.00
4  2021-01-05  0.25  0.50  0.00  0.00  0.25
```

Would this work for you?

Comment: Many thanks @Krishnakanth Allika

Comment: @fjurt, you're welcome. You ask some interesting questions.

Comment: thanks, it's for my master thesis in finance:)

Comment: Good luck with your thesis

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply(...,axis=1)` and `clip` the values with a max of 0.5 (this assumes `Date` is always the first columns - alternatively, we could set it as an index):

```
df1[df1.columns[1:]] = df1[df1.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x:x/sum(x), axis=1).clip(upper=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for col in df1.columns:
   df1[col] = df1[col].apply(lambda x: x/sum(df1[col]) if x/sum(df1[col]) < 0.5 else 0.5)
```

Have fun!